# Angular what's the best way to switch states in html display

Tags: html, angular, dom

Having to decide on two different approaches for dealing with component view between loading. By "best way" I'm talking about performance, UI less blinking (less DOM renderizations), whatever you know.

Option 1: Use loading variable to hide content while not ready

```
// .scss
<styles>
  .loading {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</styles>

// .ts
this.loading = false;
this.service.getLetters().then(array => {
  this.loading = array.length === 0;
})

// .html
<div [ngClass]="{ 'loading': loading}">
  <div *ngFor="let letter in letters">
    {{letter}}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="letters.length === 0">
    No letters to be shown
  </div>
</div>
```

Option 2: Using promises to switch between html

```
// .ts
noLetters: Promise<boolean>;
lettersPromise: Promise<Array>;
letters: Array;

this.lettersPromise = this.service.getLetters();
this.noLetters = this.lettersPromise.then(letters => letters.length === 0);

// .html
<div *ngIf="(noLetters | async) === false">
  <div *ngfor="let letter in letters">
    {{letter}}
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(noLetters | async)">
  No letters to be shown
</div>
```

Option 2 seems more powerfull to me in terms it can be more flexible ? And I think the UI does blinks less..

Can I get an opinion on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css loading seems to only take effect after some time component is rendered, and currently with Option 1 I can see at the very beginning `No letters to be shown` and only then the http call arrives and does the calculation of having letters or not.
So I won't rely on css and will take the promise aproach in option 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularAnimations on routerOutlet.
Visit this page for full instructions. [angular routing animations](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations)

Angular animations are pretty fast, they are translated to CSS transitions.

Comment: On a light read this seems to be transaction between pages. I'm talking about transictions on the same page regarding data loading. 
Although usefull, doesn't seem to address my point.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a meaningful difference in terms of performance or blinking. With the promise approach you potentially have multiple subscriptions, but compared to other aspects the performance impact should be negligible.

The info about the changed variable arrives in the same loop and will result in the same number of render changes.

Choose the method that's more comfortable for you while developing / that's easier to read. The rest just seems to be premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Why it's the reason to use Promise?

A better approach if you use Observables

```
<div *ngIf="{letters:observable$|async} as data">
  <div *ngfor="let letter in data.letters">
    {{letter}}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!data.letters.length">
     No letters to be shown
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the new syntax in Angular 17

```
@if (observable$|async; as letters) { 
  @for (letter of letters; track $index) {
    {{ letter }} } 
  @empty { 
    No letters to be shown 
  } 
}@else { 
  loading 
}
```

Comment: Because in my current scenario I don't use Observables, I use the lastValueFrom(Observable).
For most simple CRUD calls that's how I handle it since Http doesn't support continuously streams of data either way, and feels simpler to me